# Python: How to read space delimited data with different length in text file and parse it

Tags: python

I have space delimited data in a text file look like the following:

```
0 1 2 3

1 2 3   

3 4 5 6

1 3 5   

1           

2 3 5   

3 5
```

each line has different length.

I need to read it starting from line 2 ('1 2 3')
and parse it and get the following information:

1. Number of unique data = (1,2,3,4,5,6)=6
2. Count of each data:

   count data (1)=3

   count data (2)=2

   count data (3)=5

   count data (4)=1

   count data (5)=4

   count data (6)=1
3. Number of lines=6
4. Sort the data in descending order:

   data (3)

   data (5)

   data (1)

   data (2)

   data (4)

   data (6)

I did this:

```
file=open('data.txt')
csvreader=csv.reader(file)
header=[]
header=next(csvreader)
print(header)
rows=[]
for row in csvreader:
    rows.append(row)
print(rows)
```

After this step, what should I do to get the expected results?

Comment: count the lines, create a set of data, convert set to list and sort

Comment: `csv.reader()` defaults to comma separator. Use `csv.reader(file, sep=' ')`

Comment: Use `collections.Counter()` to count the repetitions of each number.

Comment: `csvreader` is not the right choice here.  Just use `for line in file:` / `parts = line.rstrip().split()`.

Comment: Thank you itprorh66, Sean Goldfarb, Tim Roberts and Barmar. I really appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```py
from collections import Counter

with open('data.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

lines = lines[1:]  # skip first line
data = []
for line in lines:
    data += line.strip().split(" ")

counter = Counter(data)
print(f'unique data: {list(counter.keys())}')
print(f'count data: {list(sorted(counter.most_common(), key=lambda x: x[0]))}')
print(f'number of lines: {len(lines)}')
print(f'sort data: {[x[0] for x in counter.most_common()]}')
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple brute force approach:

```
nums = []
counts = {}
for row in open('data.txt'):
    if row[0] == '0':
        continue
    nums.extend( [int(k) for k in row.rstrip().split()] )
print(nums)
for n in nums:
    if n not in counts:
        counts[n] = 1
    else:
        counts[n] += 1
print(counts)
ordering = list(sorted(counts.items(), key=lambda k: -k[1]))
print(ordering)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach

```
def getData(infile):
    """ Read file lines and return lines 1 thru end"""
    lnes = []
    with open(infile, 'r') as data:
        lnes = data.readlines()
    return lnes[1:]

def parseData(ld):
    """ Parse data and print desired results """
    unique_symbols = set()
    all_symbols = dict()
    for l in ld:
        symbols = l.strip().split()
        for s in symbols:
            unique_symbols.add(s)
            cnt = all_symbols.pop(s, 0)
            cnt += 1
            all_symbols[s] = cnt
    print(f'Number of Unique Symbols = {len(unique_symbols)}')
    print(f'Number of Lines Processed = {len(ld)}')
    for symb in unique_symbols:
        print(f'Number of {symb} = {all_symbols[symb]}')
    print(f"Descending Sort of Symbols = {', '.join(sorted(list(unique_symbols), reverse=True))}")
```

On executing:

```
infile = r'spaced_text.txt'
parseData(getData(infile))
```

Produces:

```
Number of Unique Symbols = 6
Number of Lines Processed = 6
Number of 2 = 2
Number of 5 = 4
Number of 3 = 5
Number of 1 = 3
Number of 6 = 1
Number of 4 = 1
Descending Sort of Symbols = 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```